# How to edit my code for not alert on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to edit my code for not alert on page load ?

http://jsfiddle.net/SN2t6/135/

This is my code for check image dimension, when load page it's will alert width and heigth. But i want to edit code for not alert width and heigth on page load and alert alert width and heigth on click element.

How can i do ?

```
<input id="banner_img_ads" value="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1562471633/IMG_8733quadrat900px.jpg">
<br>
<br>
<div onclick="getMeta(url, callback)">
click to check
</div>
<script>
function getMeta(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() { callback(this.width, this.height); }
}
    var banner_img_ads_input_val = document.getElementById("banner_img_ads").value;
getMeta(
    banner_img_ads_input_val,
    function(width, height) 
    {
    alert(width);     
    alert(height);     
    }
);
</script>
```

Comment: Images have no `onload` event. What are you looking to achieve?

Comment: If you don't want alert on page load, why not remove the img.onload line and add only a function, that read the image properys and alert the width and hight.

Comment: I think it would be great if you mark this question as answered, by checking any of the below answers as the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a click event listener

```js
function getMeta(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() { 
      callback(this.width, this.height); 
    }
}

var trigger = document.querySelector('.trigger');

trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  getMeta (
    document.getElementById("banner_img_ads").value,
    function(width, height) {
      alert(width);     
      alert(height);     
    }
  );
})
```

```html
<input id="banner_img_ads" value="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1562471633/IMG_8733quadrat900px.jpg">

<br>
<br>

<div class="trigger">click to check</div>
```

Comment: can i use call function ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You may set the width and height in a hidden element then add the jquery code below.

```
<input type="hidden" id="widthValue">
<input type="hidden" id="heightValue">

<input id="banner_img_ads" value="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1562471633/IMG_8733quadrat900px.jpg">
<br>
<br>
<div onclick="getMeta(url, callback)">
click to check
</div>
<script>
function getMeta(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() { callback(this.width, this.height); }
}
    var banner_img_ads_input_val = document.getElementById("banner_img_ads").value;
getMeta(
banner_img_ads_input_val,
function(width, height) 
{
$("#widthValue").val(width);
$("#heightValue").val(height);
}
);
</script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#YOURELEMENTID").click(function(){
    alert($("#widthValue").val());
    alert($("#heightValue").val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="banner_img_ads" value="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1562471633/IMG_8733quadrat900px.jpg">
<br>
<br>
<div class="show-alert">click to check</div>
<script>
$('.show-alert').on('click', function(){
    var url = $('banner_img_ads').attr('value');

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;

    alert(img.width);     
    alert(img.height);
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o7bva90q/

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that you need to setTimeout for the alert so that the image is finished loading then alert box pop up. You give this question a jQuery tag but your code does not have any jQuery in it. Make sure you have good indentation which helps us read the code easily. In case you want to see how your code is done in jQuery

https://jsfiddle.net/trungkim2201/sug7hLdn/

```
setTimeout(function() {
    alert("Height: " + $image.height() + ", Width: " + $image.width()); 
 }, 100)
 // give it sometime to wait for the image to load
```

Happy coding